# Facebook API checkins not working?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Wondering if anybody has had any problems using the facebook graph api to get checkins.

https://graph.facebook.com/me/checkins?access_token=2227470867|2.SOgfV3_Dc6iX_IzJctERXA__.3600.1292436000-666790342|UPcbXaafo7G5rd2I_7d9_LpeZFo

returns

```
 {
   "data": [

   ]
}
```

and any other ids insted of "me" return the same.

Anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out you can't access the fb places api outside the US

Comment: tsk, tsk. So that's why it didn't also work when I tried using it the other day.

Answer (score 1):

Allright fellows,

after some tries I can shed a light to this topic, here comes the description of the solution.

You can make such requests only by authorized apps.

I implemented the flow on Android and works like a charm,

here is an example call grabbed from logs:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/me/checkins?format=json&sdk=android&access_token=<access_token>
```

*important note:* access token MUST have been retrieved by your application, which has permissions for

```
"user_checkins", "friends_checkins"
```

getting access token is straight forward flow, explained well in all SDKs (p.s. I'm using Facebook-AndroidSDK)

Comment: I cannot set these permissions in "Permissions" section of settings of my app. How did you do it ?